# Moving files older than into subfolders

Tags: powershell, null

I'm trying to move old files into folders based on creation date. The setup is that the script should check a folder for files older than 5 years and then put them in folders sorted by year with subfolders for each month.

```cs
$SourceDir = "C:\Test"
$DestinationDir = "C:\Archive\Test\"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddYears(-5)

$files = Get-ChildItem $SourceDir * | Where-Object {
    !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit
}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('MM-MMM')

    if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
        New-Item $directory -Type Directory
    }
    Move-Item $file.FullName $Directory
```

I get this error

```
PS C:\Scripts> .\SortIntoMonths5Year.ps1
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\SortIntoMonths5Year.ps1:11 char:69
+ $Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString <<<< ('yyyy') + "\" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('MM-MMM')
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToString:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\SortIntoMonths5Year.ps1:13 char:16
+ if (!(Test-Path <<<<  $Directory))
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\SortIntoMonths5Year.ps1:17 char:10
+ Move-Item <<<<  $file.FullName $Directory
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it myself

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Test"
$DestinationDir = "C:\Archive\Test\"

$files = get-childitem $SourceDir * | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddYears(-5)}
#$files = get-childitem $SourceDir *

foreach ($file in $files) 

{

$Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('MM-MMM')

if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}
Move-Item $file.fullname $Directory 
}
```